# Decryption error with golang using RSA crypto package

Tags: dart, go, encryption, rsa

I am using `dart/flutter` package `encrypt` to encrypt a string like this:

```dart
Future<String> encryptPIN({required String pin}) async {
    final RSAPublicKey publicKey;
    final publicPem =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/keys/private-key.pem');
    publicKey = RSAKeyParser().parse(publicPem) as RSAPublicKey;

    final encrypter =
        Encrypter(RSA(publicKey: publicKey, encoding: RSAEncoding.OAEP));
    final encryptedPIN = encrypter.encrypt(pin).base64;
    return encryptedPIN;
  }
}
```

And trying to decrypt using golang

```golang
func Decrypt(rsaPrivateKey *rsa.PrivateKey, cipherText []byte) []byte {
    hash := sha256.New()
    r := rand.Reader
    label := []byte(nil)
    decryptedSum, err := rsa.DecryptOAEP(hash, r, rsaPrivateKey, cipherText, label)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return decryptedSum

}
```

The dart side works, the encryption happens but the golang side fails with an error `crypto/rsa: decryption error`.
What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: *encrypt* only supports SHA-1 for OAEP (various issues, see e.g. [#285](https://github.com/leocavalcante/encrypt/issues/285)), while SHA-256 is applied on the Go side. Fix: Switch to SHA-1 in the Go code or use a library that also applies SHA-256 on the Dart side (e.g. *PointyCastle*; note that *encrypt* is only a *PointyCastle* wrapper).